# Assigning tabular database connection id to a variable to build dynamic query

Tags: t-sql, ssas, ssas-tabular

Scripting out the partitioning of tabular cubes.

I need to assign the current connection ID to a variable-which can be found by navigating to the connection properties of that tabular database under the connection folder in object explorer.

I have been able to get all the metadata I need, minus the connection ID.

How can I assign this ID to a variable?

**Edit:**  To be clear-this is the DataSourceID for the SQL DB that is the datasource for the analysis services DB.